# Regular Expression for username with special rules?

Tags: javascript, regex

Username rule:

- length 8-30
- special character allowed: . _
- start with a character only `[a-zA-Z]`
- can not start with a number but can have numbers in between
- can have multiple full stops (`.`) in between
- can have multiple underscores only in middle.

I tired regular expression like :

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_-])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*){8,}$
^([\w]){8,}$
```

but none of them is working

Comment: Can you add some username samples that should pass the expression, and some that should not?

Comment: Please share some versions of valid and invalid usernames, this makes it much more easy to understand what you are trying to do. For example, what does *can have multiple underscores only in middle* mean? In the mathematical middle? After the first and before the last char?

Comment: The rules are a bit vague, try [`^(?=.{8,30}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]*[a-zA-Z0-9.]$`](https://regex101.com/r/LYPVMR/1). Please provide a comprehensive list of test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That should be an answer rather than a comment, along with an explanation of how it's composed and what you tested it against.  a "comprehensive" list of test cases is probably pretty huge, given the number of possible combinations. Perhaps you meant 'representative' set of test cases? :)

Comment: `in between` ... Between _what_ exactly ??

Comment: Rohit123, rohit123, rohit_123, rohit.yadav.123, rohit.yadav_123, rohit123_
These are to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! Use a tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to make your life easier.

I think this regex will meet your needs:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._]{6,28}[a-zA-Z0-9_]$
```

regex101 has the added advantage of explaining each step in detail. Also it's free.

Comment: Just made a modification in your expression : ^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9._]{6,28})[a-zA-Z0-9_]$. Now its perfect.